# Android Studio: No resource identifier found for attribute 'targetSdkversion' in package 'android'

Tags: android

Here is the error in my gradle build console:

```
Error:(7) No resource identifier found for attribute 'targetSdkversion' in package 'android'
```

I believe this is the code that is causing the error...

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"
          android:targetSdkversion="21" />
```

I've went into properties and set the target sdk version to 21 (Android 5.0).

Any suggestions as to what is causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capitalization is not correct.

You should be using `android:targetSdkVersion` (capital **V**) instead of `android:targetSdkversion`.

This is what your `uses-sdk` block should look like with this change:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"
          android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Answer (score 1):

android:targetSdkVersion was added in api level 4 that is android 1.6. Make sure you are compiling your project with 1.6 and above and you have not set 1.5 as build target. i.e **compileSdkVersion** in **build.gradle** should be greater than or equal to 4.